# how to stop query sparql jena after time even if I have not received a response

Tags: sparql, jena

I need to run this query several times if nothing returns or does not respond.

Endpoint:

```
http://opendata.comune.arezzo.it/services/lod/sparql
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p
WHERE
  { ?s a <https://ldp.ldpgis.it/ontologies/1/ldpgisOntology/LdPOntology.rdf#clAccessoEsterno>.
    ?s    ?p  ?o
  }
```

If I run this query on their [website](http://opendata.comune.arezzo.it/services/lod/snorql/?query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%20%3Fp%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fldp.ldpgis.it%2Fontologies%2F1%2FldpgisOntology%2FLdPOntology.rdf%23clAccessoEsterno%3E%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fp%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A) it returns this message:

> Could not parse server response (incomplete result due to timeout?)

This is my code:

```
Boolean success = false;
ResultSet results = null;


success = false;
int maxRepNumber = 2;
ParameterizedSparqlString qs = new ParameterizedSparqlString(Query above);
QueryEngineHTTP exec = QueryExecutionFactory.createServiceRequest(endpoint.getEndpointUri(), qs.asQuery());

while (success == false && maxRepNumber > 0) {
    try { exec.setTimeout(120000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 120000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
          results = exec.execSelect();
          success = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        maxRepNumber--;
    }                   
}
if(success == true){//do things}
```

when i run this code it works for the first few cycles of while and at the last it gets stuck during the execution of `results = exec.execSelect();`.

What I would like to do is **stop the query execution after a certain time**, **even if I have not received a response**. Is it possible?

Thanks

**EDIT =>  Solved in the comments below!**

Comment: that's what the timeout is supposed to do. Not that I understand why you'd run the the same query multiple times, but ok. If this kind of timeout does not work, you can use Java threads. And don't forget to call `exec.close()`

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. If the endpoint don't aswer I need to try again, this is why I try multiple times. Timeout does not works, and I'm already using Java Threads. If I use `exec.close()` after `results = exec.execSelect();` it will be never execute because the execution gets stuck at `results = exec.execSelect();`

Comment: Well, yes. You have to create a new one. Please try `while (success == false && maxRepNumber > 0) {
    try (QueryEngineHTTP exec = QueryExecutionFactory.createServiceRequest(endpoint.getEndpointUri(), qs.asQuery())
) { exec.setTimeout(120000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 120000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
          results = exec.execSelect();
          success = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        maxRepNumber--;
    }                   
}` - and you might also just be blocked if you're running too many requests in a short time

Comment: your solution seems to be working. Thank you. I'll run a couple more tests and let you know. If it works, you can write down the answer and I'll mark it as correct.